# Is gravitomagnetism a thing or just an analogy to explain why object precess near massive object?

Tags: gravity, magnetic-fields

I browsed a couple of articles treating gravity like a bar magnet, explaining how object can precess in the vicinity of gravity well using analogy of motion of charged particle in magnetic field. So I would like to know if gravitomagnetism do exist and if so what is it? Also why do people still use it when there is no opposite charge for gravity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gravitomagnetism** is a general term used for the field effects associated with the relative motion of masses.

Under traditional C19th Newtonian theory, students were taught that the principle of relativity only applied to bodies with uniform rectilinear motion. If we accelerated or rotated, we could tell that we were "really" accelerating or rotating (and by how much), by the geeforces that we felt, and which could be measured on our equipment. So velocity was supposed to be a purely *relative* property, but rotation and acceleration were supposed to be *absolute*.

**[Ernst Mach (1838-1916)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Mach)** disagreed. Mach pointed out that whenever we experience rotational or accelerational gee-forces, we are always rotating or accelerating *relative to the background starfield*. It was possible to claim that rotation and acceleration were *also* purely relative effects, if we said that the relative rotation and acceleration of masses was associated with gravitational side-effects.

So, imagine that you are standing at the Earth's equator and fire a rocket straight up into the sky. For an observer drifting in space, the rocket is seen to end up moving in an effectively  straight line with respect to the background stars once it leaves the Earth's influence. But to you, back on Earth, the rocket is seen to veer Westward and to end up marking out a spiral, still travelling away from the Earth, but passing overhead once every 24 hours.
According to Mach, you could legitimately claim that the Earth is *not* rotating, but that the surrounding shell of stars rotating around the Earth is creating a field that drags the rocket around to the West.

**[Albert Einstein (1879-1955)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)** was inspired by Mach's insight and used it as the basis of his **general theory of relativity**, founded on the Machian idea that all motion was relative. If the relative rotation of a shell of stars produced a rotational dragging effect on its contents, and there was nothing special about those stars, then the relative rotation of the *contents* should also in turn produce a dragging effect on the *starfield*. A rotating star or planet should *also* exert a drag on nearby matter and light.

Under Einstein's 1916 general theory, gravitomagnetic fields can be generated by forcibly accelerating or rotating a mass with respect to its surroundings: the mass feels gee-forces and sees lightbeams apparently being deflected, but the **democratic principle** requires that *the surroundings* also feel forces and see lightbeams being deflected by *the mass*. So a star or planet's rotation creates an unconventional gravitational field effect that deflects other matter and light. These fields caused by *the relative motion of masses* (=gravitational "charges") can be referred to as "gravitomagnetic" fields by analogy with electromagnetism, which describes magnetic fields caused by *the relative motion of electric charges*.

Einstein described these effects in his 1921 Princeton lectures:

> What is to be expected along the line of Mach’s thought?
>
> 1. The inertia of a body must increase when ponderable masses are piled up in its
>    neighbourhood.
> 2. A body must experience an accelerating force when neighbouring masses are accelerated, and, in fact, the force must be in the same
>    direction as the acceleration.
> 3. A rotating hollow body must generate inside of itself a “Coriolis field,” which deflects moving bodies in the sense of the rotation, and
>    a radial centrifugal field as well.
>
> We shall now show that these three effects, which are to be expected
> in accordance with Mach’s ideas, are actually present according to our
> theory, although their magnitude is so small that confirmation of them
> by laboratory experiments is not to be thought of.

---

The **[Gravity Probe B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_B)** experiment (data-gathering concluded 2010) put sensitive gyroscopes into orbit around the Earth to measure the expected gravitomagnetic dragging effect of the Earth's rotation, and reported a positive result.

Rotational and accelerational gravitomagnetism are considered reasonably uncontroversial, and we can also consider higher-order derivative effects due to *time-varying* acceleration ("jerk") and rotation.

A more difficult subject is that of the dragging effects due to the *simple relative motion* of masses – while rotational gm has a velocity component, and moving black holes are thought to exhibit 100% light-dragging at their horizons – which might lead one to assume a third class of gravitomagnetic dragging effect – the existence of a full-blown velocity gm effect would complicate the relationship between general relativity and special relativity, which assumes that inertial physics is properly deal with by (flat, undistorted) **[Minkowski spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_spacetime)**.